# Word for the cause of something negative

Tags: single-word-requests

I am thinking of a word that I have forgotten. It can be used in sentences like; "I believe the [word] here is the incompetence in leadership..."

Basically, it is the cause (or a proposed cause) of something negative. I believe the word has some level of animacy, and for some reason I'm having associations with the word *perpetrator* and *offender*. I feel like it's at the tip of my tongue yet so far away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just realized what I was looking for.

The *culprit*.

*I believe the culprit here is the incompetence in leadership*.

This explains my associations with *perpetrator* and *offender*.